# Event Handling For Java Game Engine

Tags: java, game-engine

I'm writing a little game-engine in Java and want to know how to optimize my event-handling.

For event-handling I have a class `EventManager`, here you can register a `EventHandler` (`EventHandler` is simply a flag-interface). The `EventManager` scans through all the methods of the `EventHandler` and when there is a method with the `@EventCallback` annotation and it has has exactly one Paramter with a type that extends `Event`, it adds this method to an Map : `Map<Class<? extends Event>, Set<Callback>>` (a `Callback` simply saves the `Method` and its `Object` so the `Method` can be invoked later).

What i like about this kind of event-handling is, that you can name your handler-methods however you want and you can handle different events in the same class without having to implement many interfaces.

A event-handling class would look like this:

```
class ExampleHandler implements EventHandler {

    ExampleHandler(Game game) {
       game.getEventManager().registerHandler(this);
    }

    @EventCallback
    public void exampleKeyCallback(KeyPressEvent evt) {
        //I only care about key-pressing, not key-releasing in this class
        System.out.println(evt.getKey() + " was pressed");  
    }

    @EventCallback
    public void i_can_name_this_method_however_i_want(PlayerDeathEvent evt) {
        System.out.println(evt.getPlayer().getName() + " died");
    }

}
```

For example when my player dies it will send the `PlayerDeathEvent` to the `EventManager`:

```
//Inside the player-class
public void update() {
   if (health <= 0) {
      getGame().getEventHandler().fireEvent(new PlayerDeathEvent(this));
   }
}
```

and the `EventHandler` will invoke all the callbacks for this `Event`:

```
//Inside the eventmanager-class

private Map<Class<? extends Event>, Set<Callback>> eventCallbackMap = new HashMap<>();

public void registerEventHandler(EventHandler evt) {
   // find all the @EventCallback-Methods and find the Class-Type of their Paramater, 
   // then add the Method to the Set of Methods for this Class of Events.
   // for example: exampleKeyCallback(KeyPressEvent)
   //    it will be added to the Set for KeyPressEvent.class
}

public void fireEvent(Event evt) {
   Set<Callback> callbacks = eventCallbackMap.get(evt.getClass());

   for (Callback callback : callbacks) {
      callback.invoke(evt);
   }
}
```

Which invokes `i_can_name_this_method_however_i_want` with the `PlayerDeathEvent` and prints `"*Player-Name* died"` on the console.

I want to know if this is a good way to handle events and if it will be fast enough for handling the Events in the Game or if i have to change it. And if I have to change it, how can i make it better?

Comment: I like this concept. But you should completely remove the `EventHandler` interface as it does not add any value.

Comment: And you should probably walk up the class hierarchy of `evt` in `fireEvent(evt)`, as there might be event callbacks registered for a super class of `evt` (e.g. a handler that is interested in all kinds of events, or a certain category of events like `PlayerEvent`, which might be the base class of `PlayerDeathEvent` and `PlayerRespawnEvent`).

Comment: I like this flag-interface `EventHandler`, because I don't like methods that expect a `Object` as paramter. Furthermore you can only pass an instance of a own written class, because classes of the java standard library can't implement `EventHandler` and can't have any `@EventCallback`-methods. Without this flag-interface this is possible: `eventManager.registerEventHandler("Lol, I am a String");`. With the flag-interface this is not possible and classes that implement `EventHandler` should have a `@EventCallback`-method (why would you implement the interface without making such a method?)

Comment: Yes, walking up the class-hierarchy is a good idea, but what will happen if I have something like this: `@EventCallback public void a_function(Event evt) { /* do some stuff here */ }`? This would be called for every single event and I think this would slow down the event-handling very much. And if one method does this: `Thread.sleep(100);`, That would be a big problem. Should I invoke every `Callback` in an own `Thread`? Would the performance suffer much from that?

Comment: If someone wants to react to every single event (e.g. a event logger), then of course, care must be taken to not slow down the entire thing. Anyway, don't use different threads for that! You'll get severe troubles if every callback function has to be thread-safe if it wants to access its environment!